# How much fresh garlic makes how much garlic powder

Tags: garlic

How much fresh garlic (weight) makes how much (garlic powder weight)
Reason how much garlic do I buy?
Thanks
David

Comment: Garlic powder and diced garlic in a jar usually have a conversion for you, something like "1tsp BrandName garlic powder equates to 1tsp fresh garlic" ... have you checked your bottle?

Comment: I typically get about 1/3 the starting weight of the clove(s).  I'll also add my comment as an answer to the original question.